# XIST - changing row background colour in table

Tags: python

I'm a novice with XIST but I've been trying to read through their documentation on html. Unfortunately, there are no examples I could find of how to format the colour of a row in a table.

The code I have so far is:

```
            with html.table() :
                with html.th():
                    with html.td() : 
                        +xsc.Text( "Org" )
                    with html.td() :
                        +xsc.Text( "Fullname" )
                    with html.td() :
                        +xsc.Text( "Age of File" )

                # Data Rows
                exists = manifest[manifest['Org File'] == 'Exists']
                for index, row in exists.iterrows():
                    ageOfFile = str(row['Age of file'].days)
                    if ageOfFile == '1':
                        suffix = ' day'
                    else:
                        suffix = ' days'
                        
                    if int(ageOfFile) > 3:
                        bgColour = 'red'
                    elif int(ageOfFile) > 1:
                        bgColour = 'orange'
                    else:
                        bgColour = 'white'
                        
                    with html.tr() :
                        with html.td():
                            +xsc.Text('')
                        with html.td() : 
                            +xsc.Text( row['Org_Code'] )
                        with html.td() :
                            +xsc.Text( row['Org_Fullname'] )
                        #with html.td('style="background-color:"' + bgColour) :
                        with html.td():
                            +xsc.Text(ageOfFile + suffix)
```

The third-last line is what I was hoping would work (it's now commented out)

Has anyone any ideas or knowledge that would help make this work, please?

Many thanks.

Seamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial & error it turns out to be relatively simple

> with html.tr(bgcolor='Green') :